# Generic way to check if range contains value in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass

I'd like to write a generic class that holds the endpoints of a range, but the generic version kicks back a compilation error: `value >= is not a member of type parameter A`

```scala
final case class MinMax[A <: Comparable[A]](min: A, max: A) {
  def contains[B <: Comparable[A]](v: B): Boolean = {
    (min <= v) && (max >= v)
  }
}
```

The specific version works as expected:

```scala
final case class MinMax(min: Int, max: Int) {
  def contains(v: Int): Boolean = {
    (min <= v) && (max >= v)
  }
}

MinMax(1, 3).contains(2) // true
MinMax(1, 3).contains(5) // false
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were too close.

In **Scala** we have [`Ordering`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html), which is a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html), to represent types that can be compared for equality and less than & greater than.

Thus, your code can be written like this:

```
// Works for any type A, as long as the compiler can prove that the exists an order for that type.
final case class MinMax[A](min: A, max: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]) {
  import ord._ // This is want brings into scope operators like <= & >=

  def contains(v: A): Boolean =
    (min <= v) && (max >= v)
}
```